# How to display weight distribution in hidden layers of neural network?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

I have 8 inputs in the input layer.Now i want to display weight distribution of these 8 inputs in hidden layer to observe the importance of features.To make it more clear example is shown in figure ( https://pasteboard.co/GKCpA6Q.png ).I used `plotwb` function of Matlab it didn't display the weights of every input.

Actually i want to look at weights(weights connecting inputs to first hidden layer) . Larger the weight is, the more important the input.

Comment: I kindly request you to post this question here [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can't asses feature importance in such simple way for non-linear model. This only works for simple, linear models.

Comment: can we display weight distribution inputs towards hidden layer?for instance, if i have 8 inputs i want to know the distribution of weights on each input to judge the importance of feature for predicting target variable.